# Silently configure Source Control Plugin Value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-plugin

I am trying to silently configure the value in Source control plugin (Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection) in my VS 2010. Currently, I have two options, VSTS and Perforce SCM in the drop down box. I need to select Perforce SCM by default (but silently). I would like to know where these settings are stored. I did a ProcMon and all I can find is a file .vsssettings in My Documents... section but I don't think this is the file which contains changes as evenif I replace this file, the changes are not replicated. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified as I only have TFS, but I had a quick look at the registry and found these keys. Even if it's not this particular one what you're looking for, you'll probably find what you're looking for there

[image]

The reg key is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[version]_Config\SourceControlProviders

You'll see the value for the Default is the GUID starting with 4CA, which if you look at the node under SourceControlProviders, is really the ID for TFS. You'll probably find your SourceControl provider there too (hopefully)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, changing the GUID didn't helped me but this gave me a fair idea of where to search. I finally found it here:  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\CurrentSourceControlProvider